# Folding code in vim confuse me

Tags: linux, unix, vim

I have a question about code folding in Vim.  Let's say I open a file and fold some code, then I save it and quit.  Later I open the same file, and my folds are gone.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:mkview` to save folds and such when you close a file - but you have to use `:loadview` next time you use the file.

Further, you can automate this with .vimrc file. Add following to your vimrc.

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
```